# Intersperse elements into array but if array is too long, split it up

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `Set` of `userId` strings like this:

```
["1", "2", "3"....]
```

I want to loop over and convert them to this object format:

```
[
    {
        "field" : "tag",
        "key" : "user_id",
        "relation": "=",
        "value" : 1 // Insert userId here
    }, 
    etc...
]
```

And then in between the `userId` objects I need to add the object:

```
{ "operator": "OR" }
```

So the array looks like

```
[{userId object}, {OR object}, {userId object}, etc...]
```

There are an arbitrary number of `userIds` - there could be thousands. What I need to happen is, if there are more than 200 objects in the array, I need to call the function `sendObjects(array)` with that object array, and then reset the array and continue from where I left off. The array must not end in an `OR object`. How to do this??

Comment: Check out `splice()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach()` on array `numArray`:

```js
var numArray = ["1", "2", "3"];

var res = [];
numArray.forEach(function(val, index){
  var obj =  {
        "field" : "tag",
        "key" : "user_id",
        "relation": "=",
        "value" : val
  };
  res.push(obj);
  if(numArray.length-1 !== index){
    res.push({ "operator": "OR" });
  }
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, so this intersperses the OR object in between items. However, it doesn't deal with what happens when I get to the max number of 200 items allowed in `res`.